# Does the limit of function of two variables exist?

Tags: limits

Does limit $\frac{4xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ exist or not?

To remove the root, I squared the whole equation and I get
limit $\frac{16x^2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. Then I dont know how to continue working it. Can anyone help to do this questions for me please.

Thank you for your effort in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Convert to polars. $\displaystyle \lim_{r,\theta \to 0,0} \frac{2r^2\sin 2\theta}{r}=0$, and the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: either $\,x\neq 0\;$ or $\;y\neq 0\;$ when evaluating the limit, so:

$$\frac{|4xy|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le\frac{4|x||y|}{\sqrt{x^2}}=4|y|$$

and now use the squeeze theorem

Comment: can you elaborate more please?

Comment: What isn't clear? I'm assuming $\,x\neq 0\,$ , so that $\,\sqrt{x^2}=|x|\;$...all the rest is, I believe, clear.

Comment: how do you use squeeze theorem in this f?

Comment: sorry, i'm still at lost in showing whether it has a limit or not

Comment: Karen, do you know the squeeze theorem? Note that $$0\le\frac{|4xy|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le 4|y|\xrightarrow [y\to 0]{}0$$ as I showed above...

Comment: no, i dont really know how to apply squeeze theorem here. where did your squareroot y2 in denominator go?

Comment: Karen, what's your mother tongue? I'm afraid you're not completely understanding what I write to you...

Comment: Can you tell me how did you get 4|x||y|/((x^2)^1/2)?

Comment: Ok, but I also asked you something and you didn't answer......$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge\sqrt{x^2}\implies\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}}$$

Comment: Sorry, my mother tongue is mandarin.

Comment: So you assume y=0?

Comment: No Karen, I don't assume that...If you're doing multivariable calculus you *should* know this: it is elementary. Sorry, I don't speak mandarin...

Comment: Yeah, i did it 4 years ago during my high school and college now i've forgotten..